# Connection failed in asterisk CLI

Tags: asterisk, agi

I am using php version 5.3.10 and asterisk version 1.8.22.0.
I am registering one customer of a2billing in softphone and dialing one number.
In asterisk i am getting below result:

```
<SIP/myip-0000004c>AGI Tx >> 200 result=1
<SIP/myip-0000004c>AGI Rx << Connection failed
<SIP/myip-0000004c>AGI Tx >> 510 Invalid or unknown command
[Dec 30 07:59:16] ERROR[28331]: utils.c:1343 ast_carefulwrite: write() returned error: Broken pipe
[Dec 30 07:59:16] ERROR[28331]: utils.c:1343 ast_carefulwrite: write() returned error: Broken pipe
    -- <SIP/myip-0000004c>AGI Script a2billing.php completed, returning 0
```

Does anybody have any idea what is the issue?

I am getting correct credential in AGI when it is trying to connect and using those credential i can connect in mysql but from CLI> i am getting connection failed error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `php5-adodb` and `libphp-adodb`.